# Doctrine 2 join table + extra fields

Tags: field, doctrine-orm, join

I've got two tables and a join table: 'staff', 'classification' and 'staff_classification'. In the join table I've got an extra boolean field: 'showclassification'. My annotation is as follows:

```
 /**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Staff", inversedBy="classifications")
 * @JoinTable(name="staff_classifications",
 *  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="staffid", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="classificationid", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)});
 */
```

1. How do I add the extra field 'showclassifications' to the join table?
2. How do I reference the field via DQL? E.g. What query would get all of a staff's classifications that are allowed to be shown?
3. Do I place the above annotation in one class and a @ManyToMany annotation with no @joinTable in the other? E.g. @ManyToMany (targetEntity="Classification")?

Comment: Here you can find a great article about the approach to follow in this case: http://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/doctrine-2-how-to-handle-join-tables-with-extra-columns/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You want an entity that describes the relationship (StaffClassifications), which has OneToMany relationships with both staff and classifications.

ManyToMany doesn't allow you have any "extra" properties, because the join table is not an entity, and thus can't have any properties.

Comment: +1 It's the logical OO way to do things. This exact question gets asked a lot on the mailing list, and it's what the Doctrine team suggests as well.

Comment: awesome. Thanks, I'll follow that pattern and see how I go. Cheers.

Comment: Using the OO pattern, what is the answer to question 2 above? What would the DQL look like?

Comment: Somethlink like `select s, sc, c from Staff s join StaffClassificaiton sc join Classification c ...`